# How to verify on valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

How can I show a green checkbox image beside textbox on valid usage ?
I'm trying to show this when the user passed to next textbox.

Here is my code for invalid usage

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEMail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Valid1"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
runat="server" ErrorMessage="EMail is invalid"
ControlToValidate="TextBoxEMail"
ValidationGroup="Valid1" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*
[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using JavaScript (or jQuery).
Here is an example of javascript.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs"     Inherits="WebApplication1.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Site.css" />
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkMailAddress(tb) {
            var regEx = RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
            var img = document.getElementById("imgValidate");
            if (regEx.test(tb.value)) {
                img.style.display = "block";
            }
            else
                img.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" onchange="checkMailAddress(this)"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Image ID="imgValidate" runat="server" Height="18px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Ok.png" Width="22px" CssClass="validationImage" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the site.css :

```
.validationImage
{
    display:none;
}
```

The site.css is in the Content folder in the project. And the image Ok.png is in the Images folder.